# Remove all postgresql users/completely delete

Tags: postgresql, osx-mavericks

As I attempt to create my initial user account on postgresql, I am prompted for my password, though when I enter the correct one I recieve:

```
createdb: could not connect to database template1: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "thomasmurphy"
```

I am installing through brew. My thought is that somewhere along the line I've set a password different from my system one. How do I remove all users so I can reset this pass.

I get my permission denied even if I su to postgres. I have gone through every thread on stackoverflow on this issue, and have tried:

*modifying my pg hba_conf
*updating my gems and developer tools
*running brew doctor
*reinstalling postgres
*all the other command line ideas through the thread

My situation seems to not have cropped up before, which convinces me I've set a password at some point that is now tripping all of my attempts. Adding to this theory is that I have a postgres setup on my work computer, also on mavericks, function perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that unless you changed defaults, homebrew installs Postgres with you as the superuser rather than as the postgres user. The issue might be that you're trying to use postgres "as normal" whereas it doesn't need or event want the usual postgres user references.

You see the list of users on the system using `cat /etc/passwd`, and you can change an arbitrary password by running `chpass` as root.

Comment: Right, on my other boxes install of postgres, I am the superuser, and all is well. Somehow there is a different password set for user 'root' on this install though. I didn't change any of the defaults. I may need to do a fresh install of Mavericks.

Comment: If you can run `sudo su` and log in as root that way in Terminal, you've no need to reinstall anything.

Comment: I agree that would be the case usually, however when su to root, I receive: createdb: could not connect to database template1: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "root"

Comment: No no, I was meaning: if you can log in as root using `sudo su` (no more, no less); not when you try to createdb *as* root using `sudo`.

Comment: Oh, well yes, I can accomplish that

Comment: So in that case you can stick to reinstalling Postgres if needed, rather than reinstalling OSX — which seems a bit overkill. ;-)

Comment: I agree. Thanks for your time. I'll accept your answer if you don't mind. There's something mysterious going on with permissions and postgres, so I'll keep diving through conf and password files.

Comment: Try running: `sudo su`, and then `psql -U thomasmurphy`. As root, you might be able to get in without being prompted for a password.

Comment: Good thought, will try when I'm back in home coding lair tonight~work coding lair awaits